# TC (traffic control) in Linux

Tags: trafficshaping

I am using the code in this page to limit my upload and download bandwidth.

https://help.atmail.com/hc/en-us/articles/201566464-Throttling-Bandwidth-using-Traffic-Controller-for-Linux

The code:

```
TC=/sbin/tc

IF=eth0             # Interface

DNLD=1mbit          # DOWNLOAD Limit

UPLD=1mbit          # UPLOAD Limit

IP=0.0.0.0     # Host IP

U32="$TC filter add dev $IF protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u0"

start() {

$TC qdisc add dev $IF root handle 1: htb default 30
$TC class add dev $IF parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate $DNLD
$TC class add dev $IF parent 1: classid 1:2 htb rate $UPLD
$U32 match ip dst $IP/0 flowid 1:1
$U32 match ip src $IP/0 flowid 1:2

}

stop() {

$TC qdisc del dev $IF root

}

restart() {

stop
sleep 1
start

}

show() {

$TC -s qdisc ls dev $IF

}

case "$1" in

start)

echo -n "Starting bandwidth shaping: "
start
echo "done"
;;

stop)

echo -n "Stopping bandwidth shaping: "
stop
echo "done"
;;

restart)

echo -n "Restarting bandwidth shaping: "
restart
echo "done"
;;

show)

echo "Bandwidth shaping status for $IF:"
show
echo ""
;;

*)

pwd=$(pwd)
echo "Usage: tc.bash {start|stop|restart|show}"
;;

esac
```

I changed the "IP=0.0.0.0" and "$IP/0" so it can be used in any machine (with all IPs).

When I test it with websites like : http://www.speedtest.net/ to see the effect, my upload is 1mbps (as I configure in the file) but the download does not listen to my order. The bandwidth for download is much higher that the configured value.

the default value:

Bandwidth shaping status for eth0:

```
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: root refcnt 2 bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
Sent 108 bytes 2 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
```

the value after the filter:

Bandwidth shaping status for eth0:

```
qdisc htb 1: root refcnt 2 r2q 10 default 30 direct_packets_stat 0 direct_qlen 1000
Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
```

Does any one know what could be the issue?

Comment: That's because `tc qdisc` can only control outbound traffic, not inbound. I believe you can use a `filter` with `police rate` to do that, but I'm not sure. I only have experience using `tc` in gateways, limiting speed of clients but not of itself.

Answer (score 3):

Did you use the code in this configuration:

```
TC=/sbin/tc

IF=eth0             # Interface

DNLD=1mbit          # DOWNLOAD Limit

UPLD=1mbit          # UPLOAD Limit

IP=0.0.0.0     # Host IP

U32="$TC filter add dev $IF protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u0"

start() {

$TC qdisc add dev $IF root handle 1: htb default 30
$TC class add dev $IF parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate $DNLD
$TC class add dev $IF parent 1: classid 1:2 htb rate $UPLD
$U32 match ip dst $IP/0 flowid 1:1
$U32 match ip src $IP/0 flowid 1:2

}

stop() {

$TC qdisc del dev $IF root

}

restart() {

stop
sleep 1
start

}

show() {

$TC -s qdisc ls dev $IF

}

case "$1" in

start)

echo -n "Starting bandwidth shaping: "
start
echo "done"
;;

stop)

echo -n "Stopping bandwidth shaping: "
stop
echo "done"
;;

restart)

echo -n "Restarting bandwidth shaping: "
restart
echo "done"
;;

show)

echo "Bandwidth shaping status for $IF:"
show
echo ""
;;

*)

pwd=$(pwd)
echo "Usage: tc.bash {start|stop|restart|show}"
;;

esac
```

Comment: yes, exactly ! but the download part of configuration is not working !!!

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem and I've used this script in order to limit download bandwidth.

```
#!/bin/bash
export IF_INET=enp2s0
export LIMIT=300kbit

tc qdisc add dev ${IF_INET} ingress

tc filter add dev ${IF_INET} protocol ip ingress prio 2 u32 match ip dst 0.0.0.0/0 action police rate ${LIMIT} burst ${LIMIT}
tc filter add dev ${IF_INET} protocol ip ingress prio 2 u32 match ip src 0.0.0.0/0 action police rate ${LIMIT} burst ${LIMIT}
```

Hope it works for you !